# Baby gold potatoes instead of yukon gold in a beef stew

Tags: beef, potatoes

As the title states I went to 3 stores could not find Yukon gold potatoes. The recipe said to cut the Yukon into 2 inch pieces can I just substitute baby gold gold potatoes that around 2 inches?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. This is not a problem. The size recommendation is for two reasons: cooking time, and ease of eating. Your substitution will work just fine.